# Get-help yields multiple results with same name - how to pick one?

Tags: powershell, powershell-5.0

Using Windows 7, PSv5.1.  Using Get-Help for topics often returns multiple results and I can't figure out how to choose one.  For example:

```
C:\> get-help about_parallel

Name                              Category  Module                    Synopsis
----                              --------  ------                    --------
about_Parallel                    HelpFile                            Describes the Parallel keyword, which runs the
about_Parallel                    HelpFile                            Describes the Parallel keyword, which runs the
```

I tried piping it through format-list to see if there's a more specific name but it doesn't help:

```
C:\> get-help about_parallel | fl

Name          : about_Parallel
Category      : HelpFile
Synopsis      : Describes the Parallel keyword, which runs the
Component     :
Role          :
Functionality :
Length        : 1703

Name          : about_Parallel
Category      : HelpFile
Synopsis      : Describes the Parallel keyword, which runs the
Component     :
Role          :
Functionality :
Length        : 1703
```

I also tried the online version which throws an error:

```
C:\> get-help -online about_parallel

Name                              Category  Module                    Synopsis
----                              --------  ------                    --------
about_Parallel                    HelpFile                            Describes the Parallel keyword, which runs the
about_Parallel                    HelpFile                            Describes the Parallel keyword, which runs the
get-help : Multiple Help topics were found. Use only one Help topic with the -Online option.
At line:1 char:1
+ get-help -online about_parallel
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Get-Help], PSInvalidOperationException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidOperation,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetHelpCommand
```

I have also tried update-help and then running the above again - no effect.

Desired outcome - get-help syntax to pick one of the above about_parallel help documents.  Also, when there are duplicate entries like this, how do I pick one or fix my system so there aren't duplicates?

This can't be that hard, but I can't figure it out.  Also - it's not just this one example - there are dozens of duplicates like this.

Any suggestions appreciated.

Thanks--Jim

Comment: | select -first 1 ?

Comment: Related question: http://serverfault.com/questions/313570/powershell-2-how-to-eliminate-duplicate-help-entries

Comment: @Mark - interesting idea.  Tried and it doesn't work, "get-help about_parallel | select -first 1" --> blank line...

Comment: @Mark - also checked out the serverfault thread you mentioned.  This is a similar (same?) problem, but none of what was posted works/helps me.  The workarounds listed in the thread do not work for me.

Comment: `get-help about_parallel | % Clone`

Comment: @PetSerAl - It's not exactly what I want because it doesn't let me pick one, instead it shows both.  But it works - thanks.  I'd vote it correct but I don't think I can do that for a comment???